# Multiple Emails with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send emails to mutiple people with different bodies using one code, using PHPMailer via SMTP. My code is as follows :

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{   
require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
$mail->Host       = "xxxxxxxx"; 
$mail->SetFrom('xx@xxx.com');
$mail->Subject    = "System Change";

$add = array("a", "b", "c");
foreach ( $add as $address ) {
$current = clone $mail;
if ( $address == 'a' ) 
{
    $current->AddAddress('xx@xx.com');
    $current->MsgHTML("Message1");
    $current->send();
} 
if ( $address == 'b' ) 
{
    $current->AddAddress('xx@xx.com');
    $current->MsgHTML("Message2");
    $current->send(); 
}
if ( $address == 'c' ) 
{
    $current->AddAddress('xx@xx.com');
    $current->MsgHTML("Message3");
    $current->send(); 
}
}
exit;
if($mail->Send())
{ echo "SUCCESSFUL"; }
else echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";
exit;
}
?>
```

The issue is it is sending mails but only sending the first 2, and then displaying a timeout error. Is there any setting that I need to change or is it a problem with my code? Have edited it in many ways but it ends up sending only 2 mails instead of 3. Appreciate any help :) Thanks!

Comment: Little warning form own experience: I would recommend calling ```$current->ClearAllRecipients( )``` after you send the mail. This prevents sending the second mail to the first recipient also when ```$current->send()``` is called

Comment: To add: `$mail->ClearAddresses();`, `$mail->ClearCCs();`, `$mail->ClearBCCs();`, `$mail->clearAttachments();`

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer. Update it.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I just realised, though it is working after I put the time limit. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will likely solve your issue, there is no need to clone the PHPMailer object.

I have sent hundreds of emails at once using this method with no timeout issues.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{   
    set_time_limit(120);
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
    $mail->Host       = "xxxxxxxx"; 
    $mail->SetFrom('xx@xxx.com');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject    = "System Change";

    $add = array("a", "b", "c");

    foreach ( $add as $address ) {
        $mail->clearAttachments();
        $mail->clearAllRecipients();

        if ( $address == 'a' ) 
        {
            $mail->AddAddress('xx@xx.com');
            $mail->Body("Message1");
            $mail->send();
        } 
        if ( $address == 'b' ) 
        {
            $mail->AddAddress('xx@xx.com');
            $mail->Body("Message2");
            $mail->send(); 
        }
        if ( $address == 'c' ) 
        {
            $mail->AddAddress('xx@xx.com');
            $mail->Body("Message3");
            $mail->send(); 
        }
    }

    if($mail->send()) echo "SUCCESSFUL";
    else echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";

    exit;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thankyou for responding :) I tried this code, but yet it is sending only 2 mails..

Comment: May I ask the SMTP server you're using? Does it have any restrictions? There is something happening on that side of things, do you have access to the logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error logs are showing no errors

Comment: You should contact your host tbh, this should not be an issue let alone take long enough to timeout. Oh make the last `$mail->send()` by the way (lowercase)

Comment: I don't think it is a server issue coz the same server is being used to send multiple emails at once for unix and it works properly. Could it be anything to do with phpmailer? I am kind of new to this so donot have much of an idea about it. And thanks I did change the last $mail->send()  :)

Comment: Shouldn't be, latest version and all? - I work for an ISP and I have it sending it out usage emails to customers, among many other notifications without issue. I wonder if they're getting delayed? No no, because you timeout.. Server issue.......

Comment: No I am using the older version of phpmailer, 5.2.9. Ok wow. I had put a time out of 120 seconds and it worked perfectly fine! Thanks though really appreciate it :)

Comment: Bear in mind this code won't work with PHPMailer 5.2.10 or later - you will need to use the autoloader or load the SMTP class manually. Better yet, use composer.

Comment: Oh fair call, didn't pay attention to the include. Thank you for the tick :)

Comment: Maybe it is better to set the time_limit in the foreach like my answer. The time_limit resets every time you call it so your code keeps working as the loops in the ```foreach``` increase

Comment: Thanks @AgeDeO will change it accordingly.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line of code after the opening of the foreach loop

```
set_time_limit(60);
```

With this line of code, you give every mail 60 seconds to be sent. This number can be as high as you want. But I should try to keep it as low as possible

You are resetting the timelimit to 60 seconds every time this piece of code is run. Resetting it back to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Base your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). Generally you don't ever want to be doing this kind of thing on a page load via a web server - run it from cron where timeouts are not an issue.

Comment: He's sending 3 emails.. That's not a load. *holds back from innuendo*

Comment: Even for a single message, SMTP is not a good thing to ever be doing on a page load, though that doesn't stop many from doing it. There are many places in the protocol that are slow, sometimes intentionally. If you have to do it, you really want to be submitting to localhost or somewhere nearby with minimal overhead.

Comment: Fair call but seriously should not be an issue you would run into for such minor usage (unless he's on dial-up connecting to dial-up)

Comment: Well, given the question, apparently not!